# Magento 2 - Calling the SearchCriteriaBuilder in a Collection gives an error

Tags: collection, magento2

I am experimenting with Magento 2 and trying to add some filtering in my collection. Hence i am calling the SearchCriteriaBuilder in the constructor.

```
namespace MyCode\MyBlog\Model\Resource\Post;

use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection {
    protected $entityFactory;

    protected $logger;

    protected $fetchStrategy;

    protected $_eventManager = null;

    protected $_resource;

    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;


      public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);

        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder=$searchCriteriaBuilder;           
    }
```

but this drops me an error.
*Missing required argument $connection of MyCode\MyBlog\Model\Resource\Post\Collection.*

When i remove the *SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder* param from the constructor works fine

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

Required parameters should be before optional.
Change constructor to

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
     SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    $connection = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Seems to work
I suppose that optional parameters are considered those that have null value. Right?
*You missed a comma after the $searchCriteriaBuilder